# How to get received bytes via bluetooth in hexadecimal?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, spp

I'm trying to receive data via bt on android device. When I'm sending bytes from terminal (for example 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40) I don't get any response (the Toast does not pop-up). I wan't to get data in hexadecimal, not as a string. Here is the code from handler:

```
 mHandler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
            {if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){

                try {
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, readBuf[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                }
            }

        };
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3
How to display received bytes in hex form?

Edit: afted using function byteToHexString() Toast pop up only when I'm sending data as ASCII characters, nothing happens while sending as hex. I can't debug it, because Android Studio can't see my device.
Modified code in handler:

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                String HexStr = null;
                    HexStr =  byteToHexString(readBuf);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,HexStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Edit 2: I can receive numbers, but only from range 0x30-0x39 - numbers assigned to chars 1-9 in ASCII. It seems like code from handler executes only while receiving ASCII numbers

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `makeText` with readBuf[0], which is of type byte, so it gets propagated to int and the method thinks it's a resource id (Lint should issue a warning there). <s>Instead, convert the byte array to String using [DatatypeConverter#printHexBinary(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary-byte:A-) and pass that to Toast method.</s>

Since javax packages are absent from the Android API, you can use `String#format` passing `%2x` as a format argument, and one byte you wish to format (it would be a loop iterating over all bytes).

If you care about speed however, this is as fast as it gets:

```
public static String byteToHexString(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(data.length*2);
    int lower4 = 0x0F; //mask used to get lowest 4 bits of a byte
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        int higher = (data[i] >> 4);
        int lower = (data[i] & lower4);
        if(higher < 10) res.append((char)('0' + higher));
        else            res.append((char)('A' + higher - 10));
        if(lower < 10)  res.append((char)('0' + lower));
        else            res.append((char)('A' + lower - 10));
        res.append(' '); //remove this if you don't want spaces between bytes
    }
    return res.toString();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what am I doing wrong but Android Studio can't resolve symbol "DatatypeConverter". I got java.lang.Object package improted.
I used: String HexStr = new String (DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(readBuf)) ;
Tried also cleaning project, sync Gradle files, Invalidate caches.

Comment: I haven't checked, but it's entirely possible that it isn't part of the Android API, despite it's standard Java. I will update the answer accordingly in a few minutes.

Comment: @Juras check it out now

Comment: Thanks for reply. But now toast pop up only when I'm sending data as ASCII. When I'm sending data as hex, nothing happens. I added edited code handler to first post.

Comment: @Juras Any exceptions raised? What is the data inside readBuf (use logging if you can't debug)?

Comment: How to use logging without recognizing device in Android Studio?

Comment: Have you tried adb directly? If your PC doesn't recognize device altogether, it seems that you should solve that first, otherwise development will be significantly harder

Comment: I have problems with debugging, tried many solutions, still not working. It's possible that msg.object is designet to store only ASCII chars?

Comment: I haven't done much with Bluetooth so I'm not sure, but being a byte array it should be able to store arbitrary data, and definitely shouldn't be limited to ASCII since both Android and Java are using some Unicode encoding underneath AFAIK.